# How to return an empty value or None on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, textacy

SAMPLE DATA: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s6MzBu5lFcc-uUZ9B6CI1YR7P1fDSm4cByFwKt3ckgc/edit?usp=sharing

I have this function that uses textacy to extract the source attribution. This automatically returns the speaker, cue and content of the quotes. In my dataset, some paragraphs have several quotations, but I only need the first one, that's why I put the BREAK in the for loop.

My problem now is that some of original data do not have quotation, so I was hoping that not only will the function skip it, it will also return something. I believe the problem is after the EXCEPT:

It returns something like this:

[image]

But its supposed to skip the first line because the first line returns an error so Im hoping for it to look like this:

[image]

```
import textacy 
from textacy import extract
import spacy

def extract_direct(text):
    extracted = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in text:
        try:
            doc = nlp(i)
            a = ex.direct_quotations(doc)
            for item in a:
                mined = {'speaker': item.speaker, 'cue': item.cue, 'content': item.content}
                extracted = extracted.append(mined, ignore_index = True)
                break
        except ValueError:
            continue
    contents = news_only['index']
    extracted = pd.concat([extracted, contents], ignore_index=True)
    return(extracted)

extract_direct(dataframe['Body'])
```

Comment: What if you try this `df['content'].str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '').str.replace('",', '"').str.replace(',', ' ')`

Comment: I don't understand how replace would solve that

Comment: Your Post says, what you desired, So, when I saw your raw DF and required one I feel the difference in `content` column where you have tuple like values, but you are stripping them off in desired outcome, isn't that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to solve the problem. Had to append both instances at Try and Except.

```
def extract_direct(text):
extracted = pd.DataFrame()
for i in text:
    try:
        doc = nlp(i)
        a = ex.direct_quotations(doc)
        for item in a:
            mined = {'speaker': item.speaker, 'cue': item.cue, 'content': item.content}
            extracted = extracted.append(mined, ignore_index = True)
            break
    except ValueError:
        mined = {'speaker': 'None', 'cue': 'None', 'content': 'None'}
        extracted = extracted.append(mined, ignore_index = True)
return(extracted)
```

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. Next time, could you provide a code sample that actually runs as is, without leaving out imports and variable definitions? As your question was posted, it makes it very hard for people to assist you... Remember, the better your question, the better the answer